# join prometheus queries while keeping data from the left side

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

I want to build promql query that joins two vectors: one with some metrics and other is informational. The caveat is that info vector doesn't have all the information for "joining label", but I don't want to miss the data from metrics vector.

For example: `kafka_consumergroup_lag` is the metrics vector with `consumergroup` label, and `catalog_entities_info` is the gauge info vector with `consumergroup` and `team` label and `1` gauge value for every entry. I want to add `team` label to `kafka_consumergroup_lag`. But `catalog_entities_info` doesn't have all `consumergroup` and in this case I want to add empty `team` (or maybe some placeholder, or even not adding anything at all) into resulting vector.

So far I tried:

```
(sum(kafka_consumergroup_lag[1d]) by (consumergroup) >= 100)
* on(consumergroup) group_left(team)
catalog_entities_info
```

but this query will filter out lagging `consumergroup`s which are absent in `catalog_entities_info`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now the only solution I have is with query duplication:

```
(
  (sum(kafka_consumergroup_lag[1d]) by (consumergroup) >= 100)
  * on(consumergroup) group_left(team)
  catalog_entities_info
)
or ignoring(team) (sum(kafka_consumergroup_lag[1d]) by (consumergroup) >= 100)
```

First half will add `team` label where possible, and second `or` half will add missed data (important to merge vectors while ignoring added `team` label, otherwise we will have duplicates).

Comment: it's okay for your case, but why "+" operator?) if the gauge value is "1" and the only intention is enriching the labels, it would be more informative to use multiplication (*) -->  smth*1=smth

Comment: yeah, typo (in question and answer ), should be `*`